# What are the "Faux Edges" on Meshlab?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, meshlab

I have found the concept of **Faux Edges** in several  [Meshlab](http://meshlab.net) filter descriptions. For example, in the `Stratified Triangle Sampling` filter, where the description of one of the options is:

```
Sample NonFaux Edges: Only the non-faux edges of the mesh are uniformly sampled.
```

[image]

What are the Faux (and NonFaux) Edges for meshlab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faux (from French, fake) Edges are artificial hidden edges that decompose a polygonal face into triangles. They are automatically inserted by VCGLib when reading a non-triangular mesh to be stored as an internal triangle mesh and to be able to apply many algorithms that are only defined for triangle meshes.

By definition, a pure-triangular mesh has no *faux edges*.

For example, when the well-know `Blender Suzanne Monkey` model (formed by  quad and triangle faces)

[image: Original Suzanne Monkey]

is loaded into meshlab as a quad mesh, but one *faux edge* per quad is added under the hood to store it as a triangle mesh. In the image below *"Real"* or *"Nonfaux"* edges are rendered in black, while *Faux edges* are rendered in red.

[image: Faux Edges in Suzanne]

Unless explicitly indicated, any algorithm that operates on edges (for example, `Select crease edges`) will only operate on *"real edges"* and not on *faux edges*, but many other algorithms (for example, `Laplacian Smooth`) will operate use faux edges to compute the smooth filters as if the mesh is formed only with triangles.

Internally, the edges have one [VCG flag](http://vcglib.net/flags.html) to determine if they are *faux* or not, but normally this is not exposed to MeshLab users.

Upon saving a mesh with faux edges, those will not be saved into the file. So  internal triangles of the model that share a *faux edge* will be joined into a polygonal face.